# jQuery's addClass doesn't add a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm busy on a register form. One of the steps is to choose your gender:

[image: reg]

now, the desired result is, if someone clicks the male icon, the icon gets a blue color, and when someone clicks the female one, that one turns pink.

The color switching thing works when hovered, but not when clicked. This is my HTML:

```
<div id="submenugender">
    <div class="submenu"><div class="sprite male" id="setmale"></div></div>
    <div class="submenu"><div class="sprite female" id="setfemale"></div></div>
</div>
```

It seems pretty simple. So the `.sprite` class is loaded, which just sets de default height and width + it loads the sprite. Then the `male` and `female` classes are loaded, which contain a `background-position` element:

```
#registercontainer .submenu .male {
    background-position: -7px -462px;
}

#registercontainer .submenu .female {
    background-position: -60px -462px;
}

#registercontainer .submenu .male:hover, #registercontainer .submenu .male .active {
    background-position: -7px -397px;
}

#registercontainer .submenu .female:hover, #registercontainer .submenu .female .active {
    background-position: -60px -397px;
}
```

There are some ID's and stuff here that miss in the HTML, those are just wrappers for positioning.

As you see, I created an `active` class in CSS for when someone clicks. The position set there is the colored one.
Now, when someone clicks an icon, I want it to see the active class, and change color. This is done by jQuery:

```
 $("#setmale").click(function() 
  {
      $('#registercontainer .submenu .male').addClass('active');
  });
  $("#setfemale").click(function() 
  {
      $('#registercontainer .submenu .female').addClass('active');
  });
```

But the stupid thing just won't work... Did I make any mistakes with the selector or anything?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show some more HTML? Where is `#registercontainer`?

Comment: @putvande `#registercontainer` is the absolute parent, everything is stored in there. It contains a seperate background and margins. It runs like this: `#registercontainer` -> `#submenugender` -> `.submenu` -> `.sprite` -> `.male/.female`

Comment: My +1 for a detailed question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really easy solution to what you have is to just change your css to this;

```
#registercontainer .submenu .male:hover, #registercontainer .submenu .male.active {
    background-position: -7px -397px;
}

#registercontainer .submenu .female:hover, #registercontainer .submenu .female.active {
    background-position: -60px -397px;
}
```

Notice that the `.male.active` and `.female.active` are chained together. [Read more about css chaining](http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/)

Also a little improvement to your JS code would be to change your click code to just `$(this).addClass('active');` as `$(this)` is the element which raised the click event.

*Your js is not at fault, ignore all the js answers sending you down a rabbit hole.*

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$("#setmale").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
$("#setfemale").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

or

```
$("#setmale,#setfemale").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Makes more sense! You can improve this by using `$('#setmale, #setfemale').click()` of course...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.submenu > .sprite', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    that.addClass('active');
})
```

If you want to activate **only** the clicked one:

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.submenu > .sprite', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    $('div.sprite').not(that).removeClass('active');
    that.addClass('active');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript is fine (although it could be simplified). The problem is actually the CSS:

**Wrong**

```
#registercontainer .submenu .male .active // this will match a descendant of .male
```

**Correct**

```
#registercontainer .submenu .male.active // this will match .male that is also .active
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/byb95u6p/

Simplified Version: http://jsfiddle.net/byb95u6p/1/

Comment: Is this not just the same as my answer?

Comment: @TimBJames - We posted within seconds of each other. I'll assume yours was a polite question and not an accusation.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than using `.addClass()`, You may use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) which will help you to switch your `class` using single function.

And, make sure your `selector` is right.